# error handling in Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet

Standard Ethernet has no error correction. If FCS doesn't check out fine, the frame is dropped with no further effort.
Ethernet doesn't notify the switch at the other end of the link that it 
is dropping the packet, something like ICMP of IP, neither does it ask for retransmission.

Isn't that a bit odd? One would have guessed a retransmission mechanism right when an error comes up-- before it propagates, without burdening the higher levels with overhead due to this.

In TCP for instance, a packet loss in Ethernet layer is likely to cause 
destination buffer overflows due to gaps in the byte sequence, and from there retransmission of dropped segments due to this lack of buffer space, which is a much bigger waste of resources than fixing it right at the link layer.

TIA.

//=================================

EDIT:

The Q here is:

Why doesn't Ethernet have a retransmission mechanism when there is a CRC error? That is, 
when the receiving switch sees an error on the frame, why doesn't the it 
ask the sending switch at the other end of the link to retransmit the frame? Or doesn't even just notify the sender?

Ethernet is just dropping the packets whenever there are such errors. Without any retransmission or notification, the packet loss won't be discovered 
until some other control mechanism in an upper layer protocol.

Wouldn't it be a sound logic to make Ethernet at least notify the sender? Is retransmission overhead the only reason for 
not having an elaborate error handling?

Comment: You have laid out the situation, and I don't really see a question.

Comment: You can ask Bob Metcalfe, the creator of ethernet. He is at the University of Texas at Austin. Ethernet was a college project of his. It was originally designed for a shared medium. There were many competing physical/data-link protocols. The market eventually settled on ethernet, which has now been dethroned as the king of the LAN, by Wi-Fi (there are more Wi-Fi interfaces shipped than ethernet interfaces). Wi-Fi is much more complex than ethernet, and it adds a bunch of frame types and other features.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Ethernet isn't point-to-point. If an ethernet packet is corrupted, how can you tell who to send the failure message to?

Comment: well -- the source address is right there as in any packet. that's way beside the point.

Comment: @Roam - you missed the point : How do you know it's not the source address that's corrupted?

Comment: no - youre missing the point. that can happen on any protocol-- p2p/not in your vision. nothing to do w/your argument.

Comment: (Point-to-point connection wouldn't need a source address. Only one sender). My point is you can't make 'ethernet' more robust without something of similar complexity to TCP that handles missed packets, missed acks, out of order packets, etc. And you don't need any of that when you have TCP on top. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 0):

The BER for Ethernet is very very low typically of the order of 10^(-10).
So the overhead for ACKing each frame would get higher than just ignoring errors and let upper layers handle if there is need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you won't see it very much any more....  But in a half-duplex ethernet enviroment (csma/cd) packets will be resent if a collision is detected by the transmitting stations.